# adding files to a list in a method

Tags: c#

I have a method I wrote to add some files to a list, inside the method the list contains the files, but when I step out of the method with the debugger, the list is empty.

```
List<string> lstPDFApps = new List<string>();

public void GenerateEmployeeApplication(int enrollmentId, long packageId, int carrierId)
{
    --snip--
    get.Fill(dt, carrierId, 14);
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt)
    {
        var param = new List<SqlParameter>();
        param.Add(new SqlParameter("@EnrollmentID", enrollmentId));

        param.Add(new SqlParameter("@PackageID", packageId));
        var files = dr.PDFStamp(param);
        lstPDFApps.AddRange(files.Where(file => file != ""));

    }
}
```

The list is a public list of strings

Any ideas?

Comment: double-check statement *"inside the method the list contains the files, but when I step out of the method, the list is empty"* (with debugger or code) and check if you really don't have anything like `lstPDFApps = new List<string>();` or `lstPDFApps.Clear()` after you exit method, but before you check if the list is empty.

Comment: what scope is the list declared in? maybe you need to --unsnip-- some more of your code

Comment: @Rob the list is a public list, it is declared outside of this method.

Comment: @Sinatr when I step out of the method (with the debugger) it immediately forgets what is inside of the list without hitting anything that would clear it

Comment: @Rob also, the part I snipped out was just the creation of a dataset and the table adapter.

Comment: Can we see the declaration of the member `lstPDFApps`, please?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen updated with declaration

Comment: @reds184 Are you sure that `files.Where()` is actually returning something? As a deleted answer said I'd think you'd need to call `ToList` on that.

Comment: Your `lstPDFApps` is a non-static field, so each instance of your class has its own list. Are you sure you're looking at the same class instance?

Comment: Personally, in my experience this sort of code (where a method works with a variable that is declared in outer scope) becomes more difficult to maintain over time. So, write a self-contained method that works with given inputs (parameters) and gives you the expected output/s (`return` or `out`). So `GenerateEmployeeApplication` would return a `List<string>` and `List<string> lstPDFApps = GenerateEmployeeApplication(enrollmentId, packageId, carrierId)`. Just my two cents. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot.

I was declaring the list inside the method that calls GenerateEmployeeApplication() - I'm guessing once I step out of that the list is kaput.

I moved the declaration outside any methods and it retains the information.

sorry for wasting everyone's time!

Comment: Note that if, by accident, you have _both_ a local variable `lstPDFApps` (declared inside method) _and_ a field `lstPDFApps` (variable defined on the class directly) then `lstPDFApps` without qualification refers to the local variable, and `this.lstPDFApps` must be used to access the field.